# %line directive from NASM equivalent for MASM

Tags: nasm, masm

Basically I'm writing a simple C-like language that outputs direct NASM syntax assembler. I can debug this in VS but it's kind of pain. Using MASM it's a bit more fluid debugging wise, but NASM has a %line directive that I could use to link my original source to the assembly while debugging (Note I haven't actually got this to work yet).

I can't find anyway to debug NASM assembly on Win 10 or the equivalent of the %line directive in MASM (which I can debug in VS)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use `-gcv8` with nasm to generate symbols.  Masm was never designed to be the back end for a compiler (VC++ has always used an internal assembler), so it doesn't have line number passthrough.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for the info. I have tried this but I can't see any difference in the output. Should NASM generate a separate file with symbols or are they imbedded?

Comment: I believe it will produce a `.pdb` file.  The debug symbol format is given with `-F` (capital F); you can get the list of supported formats with `nasm -h`.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks  so much for the help! You were very close and helped push my along the right path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who has trouble with this.

NASM needs something similar to below to get debug output on windows.

nasm -g -F cv8 mymain.asm -f win64 -o mymain.obj

To use the symbols and actually get a pdb file you need to tell LINK to give it to you. Both /pdb:filename and /debug are needed.

link /subsystem:console /pdb:mymain.pdb /debug /entry:mymain mymain.obj